# White screen and PHP error when attempting to access Laravel on Production

Tags: php, git, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I added my Laravel application to a Git repository. Pushed it up and pulled it down on a fully provisioned server setup I have used for previous Laravel projects. I attempt to access my site at the .com and it is rendering a white screen. Checked my Nginx log and found the following:

```
   [RuntimeException]                                                                                                         
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/laravel/bootstrap/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file   
  or directory in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17                                                         
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/laravel/bootstrap/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/u  
  sr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I read that you either have to include your vendor folder or run composer update/install. I tried both and still receive the same error. I thought maybe it is a permission thing so I ran chmod and chown according to the Laravel documentation. Still nothing. Any advice?

Comment: Almost sure it has something to do with either file permission or composer. Check your production server and see if the full vendor stack is actually there (basically the `vendor` folder and all its dependencies)

Comment: Have you run `composer update` or `composer install` on the server (or even `composer dump-autoload`)? The contents of the `vendor` folder are usually omitted from the git repository, so all the dependencies are probably missing (`composer install` or `update` will fix that).

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `composer install` on the server to install your project's dependencies. Your dependencies aren't stored in Git by Laravel (this is a best practice) so anywhere you pull the repository you must reinstall the dependencies.

This will require you to have composer installed on the server you are trying to run Laravel onto.